# Dialogflow not showing access token

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using Entrepreise Edition of Google DialogFlow Service but for some reason I cannot find the access token so I can use it for calling the dialogflow api V1.

In my code I have something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing" }),
            success: function(data) {
                var respText = data.result.fulfillment.speech;
                console.log("Respuesta: " + respText);
                setResponse(respText);
            },
            error: function() {
                setResponse("Internal Server Error");
            }
```

Where there is need of access token.

Note: If I use NOrmal accoutn for Dialogflow(non Entreprise) I can see the access token, this is quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow Enterprise supports only the v2 or v2beta1 versions of the Dialogflow API, which rely on Google Cloud IAM for authentication, not the old Developer Access Token. See the "[Setting up authentication](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup)" page in the Dialogflow V1 to V2 migration guide and the [Google Cloud authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/).